# 'request' object not getting imported from flask module

Tags: python, flask, request, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm unable to import the 'request' function from flask, it is facing some error or something I guess. Is there any solution?

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' %self.id

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[The request function is instead getting turned to a variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Oss.jpg)

Also I am facing the same kind of error in another code while trying to *import current_user from flask_login*

Is there any solution for it? or alternate way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing, if you dig deeper, is that `request` is an instance of `LocalProxy`, which is a bit of behind-the-scenes magic that ensures that what might appear to be a global variable gets the value of the specific request that invoked the handler.

What matters is what happens when you run it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. But is it the same case while importing current_user from flask_login ?

Comment: It is. https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/flask_login/utils.py#L26